# Операция симетричная разность для двух списков

Tags: c#, list

Есть операция дизъюнкции, т.е. объединения. Я хочу из двух списков взять только уникальные значения, но несовсем понятно как это сделать. Посмотрел `Except`, `Intersect` - это не то.

Вот для наглядности

```
List<string> lst1 = new List<string>(){"1","2","3"};
List<string> lst2 = new List<string>(){"1","2","4"};

//var lstRez = {"3","4"}; Вот что должно получиться в итоге, т.е. символ 4 здесь уникален в обоих списках
```

Вот как выглядит операция объединения графически

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дизъюнкция множеств - объединение, да. В результате операции объединения двух списков получится список `1, 2, 3, 4`.
На приложенной картинке не объединение, а симметрическая разность. При выполнении операции симметрической разности результат будет `3, 4` на вашем примере, уникален не только 4, но и 3.

Comment: пардон, все верно. На картинке просто знак U - я думал это объединение

Comment: сначала вычтите первый из второго потом второй из первого и объедините - два вызова Except и Concat

Comment: Уточнение: на картинке знак U означает универсальное множество

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Симметрическая разность множеств - это объединение разностей двух множеств, соответственно можно сделать так:

```
List<string> lst1 = new List<string>(){"1","2","3"};
List<string> lst2 = new List<string>(){"1","2","4"};
List<string> result = lst1.Except(lst2).Union(lst2.Except(lst1)).ToList();
```

А также у интерфейса `ISet` есть метод:

```
void SymmetricExceptWith(IEnumerable<T> other)
```

Answer (score 6):

Ещё один способ - из объединения вычесть пересечение:

```
List<string> lst1 = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
List<string> lst2 = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "4" };

var lstRes = lst1.Union(lst2).Except(lst1.Intersect(lst2));
```